# How to train an Weka AI on a dataset through Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, weka

I am currently coding an AI with the Weka API for java. I am using the MNIST handwriten digits dataset to train my AI on. The AI will train on images of handwritten digits then give you an output of if the digit is a 0, 1, 2, etc. Each "Image" is a 28x28 array with each position being a range of 0-255 to indicate a grayscale colour. I am using some code I wrote to convert the array into the ARFF file format:

```
public void createArffFromDataset(String pathName, MnistDataset dataset) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(pathName);
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(pathName);
        writer.append("@RELATION MnistDataset\n");

        for (int r = 1; r <= 28; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 28; c++) {
                writer.append("\n@ATTRIBUTE r").append(String.valueOf(r)).append("c").append(String.valueOf(c)).append(" NUMERIC");
            }
        }
        writer.append("\n@ATTRIBUTE class {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}\n\n@DATA");
        for (MnistMatrix i : dataset.dataset) {
            writer.append("\n");
            for (int r = 0; r < 28; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 28; c++) {
                    writer.append(String.valueOf(i.matrix[r][c])).append(",");
                }
            }
            writer.append(String.valueOf(i.label));
        }
        writer.close();
    }
```

This loads the dataset into a Arff file that looks like this:

```
@RELATION MnistDataset

@ATTRIBUTE r1c1 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE r1c2 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE r1c3 NUMERIC
...
@ATTRIBUTE r24c22 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE r24c23 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE r24c24 NUMERIC

@ATTRIBUTE class {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

@DATA
(Data goes here)
```

However after I have converted the dataset to a Arff format I cannot find how to train the AI on the dataset. I have looked for documentation however I cannot find one that explains what command to use / how to use the command.
A link to some documentation will be appreciated however I am quite new to machine learning so I will not be able to understand some sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use the Weka API is documented in the Weka manual (PDF) that comes with your Weka installation.

Alternatively, have a look at the Weka wiki article [Use Weka in your Java code](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/).

Finally, instead of creating an ARFF file through outputting text, you should use the Weka API directly to generate a `weka.core.Instances` object. That way, you don't even need to generate a file, as you can train your classifier with the `Instances` object. See the following Weka wiki article on [Creating an ARFF file](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/creating_arff_file/) on how to create the data structures in memory.